# jQuery MULTIPLE TABLES hover and click

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have (10+) tables that all have the same format, trying to get page to display the header and make it so when you hover over the head it display they body and when you click that head (or body) it will keep that individual head/body displayed. Also keep other ones that have already been clicked.

Only beginner jQuery-er. 
Have put 15+ hours just on this element so it's time to call for help.

Ignore pictures.

Some mess I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/XE6AG/159/
Very similar to this:http://jsfiddle.net/gRSXZ/1/ except I need tbody to be hidden then expanded on hover, stay expanded on click!

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td >
        <table class="ActiveTableAwards"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
           <thead class="ActiveTableAwardsHead">
              <tr>
                <th >
                <img height="27" src="images/pmcmsa_head.gif" width="430"    alt="pmcmsahead" /></th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody class="TextTbody">
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    <p>One </p>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <img height="200" src="images/pmcmsa.jpg" width="200" alt="pmcmsa" />   
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr> 
                <td>
                    <img height="5" src="images/separator_md.gif" width="550" alt="separator" />    
                </td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table>
       <table class="ActiveTableAwards"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
           <thead class="ActiveTableAwardsHead">
              <tr>
                <th >
                <img height="27" src="images/rd_head.gif" width="430" alt="rdhead" /></th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody class="TextTbody">
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    <p>Two</p>
                 </td>
                 <td >
                     <img height="200" src="images/rd.jpg" width="200" alt="rd" />                  
                 </td>
             </tr>
               <tr> 
                <td>
                    <img height="5" src="images/separator_md.gif" width="550" alt="separator" />    
                </td>
             </tr>

          </tbody>
       </table>
       <table class="ActiveTableAwards"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
           <thead class="ActiveTableAwardsHead">
              <tr>
                <th >
                <img height="27" src="images/merit_head.gif" width="430" alt="rdhead" /></th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody class="TextTbody">
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    <p>Three </p>
                 </td>
                 <td >
                     <img height="200" src="images/merit.jpg" width="200" alt="rd" />                   
                 </td>
             </tr>
               <tr> 
                <td>
                    <img height="5" src="images/separator_md.gif" width="550" alt="separator" />    
                </td>
             </tr>

          </tbody>
       </table>
       <table class="ActiveTableAwards"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
           <thead class="ActiveTableAwardsHead">
              <tr>
                <th >
                <img height="27" src="images/membership_head.gif" width="430" alt="rdhead" /></th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody class="TextTbody">
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    <p>Four</p>
                 </td>
                 <td >
                     <img height="200" src="images/membership.jpg" width="200" alt="rd" />                  
                 </td>
             </tr>
               <tr> 
                <td>
                    <img height="5" src="images/separator_md.gif" width="550" alt="separator" />    
                </td>
             </tr>

          </tbody>
```

**- Jquery**

```
$(".ActiveTableAwards") 
    .hover(function() {
        $(".ActiveTableAwardsHead") .toggleClass('hover') .toggle("fast", function showNext(){                                                         

          $(".TextTbody").show("slow", showNext);
          });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $(".ActiveTableAwardsHead") instead of $("ActiveTableAwardsHead")

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ActiveTableAwardsHead").hover(function() {
            $(this).children('tr').toggleClass('hover').show();
                     }
          ).hover(function() {
           $(this).fadeIn();
                      }, 
           function() {
            $(this).fadeOut();
                      });    

$(".TextTbody").children('tr').addClass('hover').click(function(){
          $(this).addClass('hover').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: The headers just disappear when hovering. Any idea what causes that?

Comment: what u need? can u expline me in detail step by step.

Comment: I would like the hover and click functions to show the tbody contents. But when you click i would like the tbody to STAY expanded and be able to keep expanding others.